# Validar Datos ingresado anteriorimente conJS

Tags: javascript, jsp

No he podido validar que los datos que trae el formulario fueron modificados, para poder generar un actualizar.

La verdad no tengo idea como hacerlo, si alguien me puede dar una idea o una ayuda, seria maravilloso.

de antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: Trata de subir algo de código para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es validar simplemente los datos que fueron digitados en el formulario por el usuario, puedes capturar dichos datos de la siguiente forma si usas sólo Js:

```
var prueba = document.getElementById("IdDelCampo").value;
```

O si usas Jquery, lo puedes capturar así: `var prueba = $("#IdDelCampo").val();`

Una vez capturados, puedes realizar una petición Ajax, que se dirija a una función ya sea PHP, donde se encuentre el procedimiento de actualizar los datos que necesites: Uptade...

Para ello, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
        url: //URL de la carpeta donde está la función,
        dataType: 'json' //TIPO DE DATO QUE TE VA A DEVOLVER ESA FUNCIÓN,
        type: 'post' //TIPO DE DATO EN QUE LA VAS A MANDAR,
        data: //LOS CAMPOS CAPTURADOS COMO TE LO ENSEÑÉ ANTERIORMENTE, O MEJOR AÚN: $('#idDelFormulario').serialize()//ÉSTO PARA MANDAR TODOS LOS DATOS DENTRO DEL FORMULARIO,
        }).done(function (respuesta) {
        if (respuesta == true) {
            //SI LA RESPUESTA ES VERDADERA, ES DECÍR, SI SÍ SE ACTUALIZÓ, PONES EL CÓDIGO QUE NECESITES AQUÍ.. EJM: alert("Actualización Exitosa!")
        } else {
        alert("No se pudo actualizar!")
        }
        if (respuesta == "error") {
        alert("Algo malo ocurrió, intenta de nuevo..!")
        }
        }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        });
```

Comment: en caso de que no sea PHP ?? y en este caso el procedimiento es a traves de servicios web...

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla si no requieres una seguridad exhaustiva y alguna posible sobrecarga de servidor es guardar el valor original en un data del input y cuando alguien haga un keyup o keydown comparar ambos valores

```
<input type="text" data-value="Valor Original" value="Valor Original">

$('input').keyup(function(){
    let data = $(this).data('value')
    let value = $(this).val()
    if (data != value) {
        //habilitar boton update
    }
})
```

Comment: Esto en el archivo del javascript o el HTML ? (los tengo separados)

Comment: los inputs que van en el formulario en el HTML y la parte js puede ir aparte o dentro del html, podrías poner más datos en tu pregunta, para saber que necesitas con más detalle.

Comment: Basicamente es un formulario donde trae los datos anteriores, y sobre el mismo input se debe hacer la modificacion de los datos... la validacion ideal es hacerla en el boton de "actualizar" que me indique si los datos anteriores son iguales a los que estoy modificando

Comment: Te sirve mi respuesta como la de @Candelo solo tienes que aplicar los cambios necesarios. En caso de que usas los data que te recomiendo, solo debes cambiar el input keyup por el boton on click.